# Postgres: select array element based on value in other column

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have two column in a postgres table, one containing an array of variable length the other the array position of the elements I want to select.
How do I query these?

```
testtable
testarray arraypos
a,b,c     3
a         NULL
          NULL
b,c,d,e   3
a,c       1
```

What I want is something like:

```
SELECT testarray[arraypos] FROM testtable;
```

i.e. getting c, d, a.

Comment: What is the output you want? Your query should work just fine

Comment: Just 2 moment: first index = 0, so arraypos -1, you exclude null positions
`SELECT testarray[arraypos -1 ] FROM testtable where arraypos is not null;`

Comment: @Shpionus: Array indexes start with `1` in Postgres, not `0`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, my fail.